# JSP validated itself first before going to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i wondered what's wrong with my code. It supposed that JSP will validate all the field, be it required, textfield format and etc first before going to the servlet. i used the following code to check jsp itself before going servlet. However, this doesn't work as it didn't fire my jsp function validation() code, it went straight to the servlet.

```
<form action="RegistrationServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validation(event);">
```

The following code will be my JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><%@page language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>

<script>





function validation(){

    var userid =document.getElementById("userID").value;
        var firstName= document.getElementById("fName").value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
        var phoneNo= document.getElementById("phoneNo").value;
        var dateOfBirth=document.getElementById("dob").value;
        var displayName= document.getElementById("dName").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var address= document.getElementById("address").value;
        var interest = document.getElementById("interest").value;
        var emailAddress = document.getElementById("emailAddress").value;
        //var profilePic=document.getElementById("profilePic").value;
        var profilePiclbl=document.getElementById("lblProfilePic").innerHTML;
    alert("cc");
alert(emailAddress);



    //first check  all whether is it empty
            //check individual whether is it empty 

        //else forward to next page & create session
            //check the format 
                // forward to next page & create session
                    //servlet check label is it empty if not send to confirmation page


            if(firstName==""){
                document.getElementById("lblfName").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblfName").innerHTML="Please fill in your first name.";
                alert("Please check your first name.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblfName").innerHTML="";
            }
            if(lastName==""){
                document.getElementById("lbllName").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lbllName").innerHTML="Please fill in your last name.";
                alert("Please check your last name.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lbllName").innerHTML="";
            }
            if(displayName==""){
            document.getElementById("lbldName").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lbldName").innerHTML="Please fill in your display name.";
                alert("Please check your display name.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lbldName").innerHTML="";
            }



            if($("#dob").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
                document.getElementById("lblDOB").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("lblDOB").innerHTML="Please fill in your date of birth.";
         return false;
                }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblDOB").innerHTML="";
            }


if(phoneNo==""){
document.getElementById("lblphoneNo").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblphoneNo").innerHTML="Please fill in your phone number.";
                alert("Please check your phone number.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblphoneNo").innerHTML="";
            }

if(userid==""){document.getElementById("lblUserID").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblUserID").innerHTML="Please fill in your user ID.";
                alert("Please check your user ID.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblUserID").innerHTML="";
            }





            if(password==""){
            document.getElementById("lblPassword").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblPassword").innerHTML="Please fill in your password.";
                alert("Please check your password.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblPassword").innerHTML="";
            }

            if(emailAddress==""){
            document.getElementById("lblemailAddress").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblemailAddress").innerHTML="Please fill in your email address.";
                alert("Please check your email address.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblemailAddress").innerHTML="";
            }

            if(address==""){
                document.getElementById("lblAddress").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblAddress").innerHTML="Please fill in address.";
                alert("Please check address.");
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblAddress").innerHTML="";
            }



             if(interest==""){
                document.getElementById("lblInterest").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("lblInterest").innerHTML="Please fill in your interest.";
                alert("Please check your interest."); 
                return false;
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("lblInterest").innerHTML="";
            }




    if(firstName!="" || lastName!="" || userid!="" || phoneNo!="" || dateOfBirth!="" || displayName!="" || password!="" || address!=""|| interest!=""|| emailAddress!=""){
 var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
 var numbers = /^\d{8}$/;  
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;


   if(!firstName.match(letters)|| !lastName.match(letters)){
   if (!firstName.match(letters)){
   document.getElementById("lblfName").style.color = "red";
   document.getElementById("lblfName").innerHTML="Please check your spelling of your first name.";
   return false;
   }else{
   document.getElementById("lblfName").innerHTML="";
   }
   if(!lastName.match(letters)){
    document.getElementById("lbllName").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("lbllName").innerHTML="Please check your spelling of your last name.";
    return false;
   }else{
   document.getElementById("lbllName").innerHTML="";
   }
    }
    //mid
    else{
    document.getElementById("lbllName").innerHTML="";
       document.getElementById("lblfName").innerHTML="";
    } 
     if(!phoneNo.match(numbers)){
         document.getElementById("lblphoneNo").style.color = "red";
     document.getElementById("lblphoneNo").innerHTML="Please check your phone number.";
     return false;
    }else {
     document.getElementById("lblphoneNo").innerHTML="";

    }


    if (!emailAddress.match(re)) { 
     document.getElementById("lblemailAddress").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("lblemailAddress").innerHTML="Please check your email address.";
     return false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("lblemailAddress").innerHTML="";
  }
    if (profilePiclbl!="") { 

     return false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("lblProfilePic").innerHTML="";
    return true;
  }






                 // $("#passRegi").val("success");
                    //alert($("#passRegi").val());

        }


}   </script>
<form action="RegistrationServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validation(event);">
Registration

<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"></td>
<td> <label for="lblfName" id="lblfName" ></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name :</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"></td>
<td> <label for="lblDOB" id="lbllName"></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Display Name :</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="dName" id="dName"></td>
<td> <label for="lblDOB" id="lbldName"></label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Date Of Birth :</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob"></td>
<td> <label for="lblDOB" id="lblDOB"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Number:</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="phoneNo" id="phoneNo"></td>
<td> <label for="lblphoneNo" id="lblphoneNo"></label></td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td>Email Address:</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress"></td>
<td><label for="lblemailAddress" id="lblemailAddress"><div style="color: #FF0000;">${errorMessage}</div></label></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td> <input type="password" name="password"  id="password" onkeyup="CheckPasswordStrength(this.value)"></td>
<td> <label for="lblPassword" id="lblPassword"></label></td>
<td><label for="password_strength" id="password_strength"></label></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="address"  id="address"></td>
<td> <label for="lblAddress" id="lblAddress"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Profile Picture:</td>
<td> <input type="file" name="profilePic"  id="profilePic"  accept="image/*"  onChange="previewFile()"></td>
<td> <label for="lblProfilePic" id="lblProfilePic"></label></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Interest:</td>
<td> <input type="text" name="interest" id="interest"></td>
<td> <label for="lblInterest" id="lblInterest"></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validation();">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because, you have some error in validation() function. You do not have userID id defined in any HTML element and therefore, validation function stop executing during the first line of validation() function and as a result it could not return any value and this cause form submission without validation.

```
var userid =document.getElementById("userID").value;  //userID is not present in any html element.
```

Please, try adding input field for userID id as well or remove it.